# THREEJS No shadow casted

Tags: javascript, three.js

so the problem is straightforward. No shadow in the scene.
At first I thought it was caused by the imported JSON format 3D models, so I added a basic cube in the middle of the scene, still not working.

**Light**

```
centerLight = new THREE.SpotLight('#fff',3);
centerLight.castShadow = true;
centerLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
centerLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
centerLight.shadowCameraNear = 500;
centerLight.shadowCameraFar = 4000;
centerLight.shadowCameraFov = 30;
centerLight.position.set(0,20,0);
centerLight.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 8), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: '#00fa00',
})));
scene.add(centerLight);
```

**Cube**

```
var shadowMakerGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var shadowMakerMar = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:'#000'});
var shadowMaker = new THREE.Mesh(shadowMakerGeo,shadowMakerMar);
shadowMaker.position.set(0,9,0);
shadowMaker.castShadow = true;
scene.add(shadowMaker);
```

**Plane used to let the shadow cast on**

```
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 50, 50);
var planeMar = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:'#fff'});
plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo,planeMar);
plane.receiveShadow = true;
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(plane);
```

And I already did this:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
```

All Code here https://github.com/ZZYW/is_shame_necessary_website/blob/master/static/js/homepage/navigation.js

Comment: maybe try to set `centerLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;` to debug the shadow frustum

Comment: For information there is a bug in firefox 35.0.1 ; I have no shadow too. The bug is reported and I tested that it is corrected in firefox 36 beta.